# add a data to the table using angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

[image: Please refer this image]

> When i entered state name and state code and clicked on add that contents should be present on that data table. How to achieve it using angular 4?? i am using angular material data table

Comment: Recreate your data source.

Comment: can u please help me how to do it

Comment: No I can't. But the documentation can. https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Comment: Follow this link [add new row to mat-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983710/add-a-new-row-into-mat-table-using-angular-4/49996015#49996015)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You need to push the data into datasource refer this link you will get a solution
>   [Add a new row](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axjzov-xc4kbp?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.ts)