# Add a new row into mat-table using angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, angular-material-5

How to add a new row into Angular Material table manually from a input field.

Please see this image in that if i add a state name and state code it should present in the following table please help me how to achieve it using Angular 4.

[image: angular material table]

Comment: Please post what you have done so far

Comment: sorry i don't have any idea on that i should try now

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've put together a quick example that should give you a good hint as to where to start from: [Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axjzov-xc4kbp)

This works by using two-way data binding on the input field to keep track of what the user typed in the form. When the `add` button is then pressed, the table is updated with a new element dynamically created with the input content.

Comment: Hi thank you it works but i have one more doubt how to add data using angular http crud

Comment: Hi .. any idea if i want the new row at top of table rather than bottom then how to do it?

Comment: @saad sure, just use `unshift` instead of `push`

Comment: unshift works ... but it gives index as 1 .. so there are multiple row with index 1.How to dynamically change row number